# File upload on shared hosting

Tags: mysql, php, website

Is it possible to upload a file of size 300+ MB on *shared hosting* such as host gator ?

Comment: You should ask this of your shared hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

Marking this as "too localized" -- The answer is it depends on your hosting company (call or email them to ask).

Many probably have an upload limit in their PHP/ASP/whatever engines (the ISP I worked at limited you to 10MB file uploads), and if you try to use more disk space or bandwidth than you're paying for you're probably in for an unpleasant "You No Can Has" of some kind (If you're lucky just a bigger bill. If you're less lucky your transfer getting stopped in the middle. If you're unlucky your site becoming a "This site has exceeded its bandwidth limits" page)